# Is it necessary to learn Java EE before learning Spring Framework?

Tags: java

I was recently hired as junior java developer and we are using Spring framework. I really like it, but the problem is: i still feel myself uncomfortable when it comes to some Spring features which i don't understand yet. I'm planning to learn Spring in depth in free time. Unfortunately i have no experience in using Java EE (actually i know nearly nothing about JavaEE. My JEE knowledges are all theoretical)...So my question is: Is it mandatory to learn JEE if i want to stay with Spring in the future? Thanks.

Comment: it is mandatory if you want to work as java developer

Comment: Who "mandates" this?

Comment: The answer is yes, learn servlets and jsps, these are necessary and spring uses Servlets in modules such as web and MVC. Try Youtube or Udemy and find a course which is best for you.

Comment: What else except Servlets and JSPs i should learn from JEE environment to start learning Spring?

Answer (score 7):

Java EE is nothing more than an extension of Java SE meaning that it's just a bunch of extra features and packages added onto Java SE. Features such as concurrency frameworks, serverlets, websockets and a whole lot more. So in other words, no you don't need to get into all of Java EE to know Spring.

Answer (score 4):

It will be always helpful if you learn some of basics about JEE. I think you should atleast have basic idea around servlets and jsp if you are planning to utilize spring MVC. Once you get hold of these basics, spring MVC plays around the same concept but with different approach. Spring has lot more than jee actually.

Comment: Actually i used to use Servlets and JSPs while studying Java before. I have small project made by Servlets concept. We use Spring MVC in our project and i'm almost ok with that. Maybe my question wasn't very accurate. I wanted to know if i MUST learn JEE in depth and then switch to Spring or i could start learning Spring without learning all JEE concepts.

Comment: Then the sufficient answer should be NO. You can grab your missing concepts parallaly while learning spring.